# Visual Basic 2010 - How can I use multiple "start To end" into For Statement?

Tags: vb.net

I have this in VB 2010...

```
For Variable_1 As Integer = 1001 To 1003
     RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & Variable_1 & " blah.")
Next
```

That prints in to a RichTextBox...

```
Blah blah 1001 blah.
Blah blah 1002 blah.
Blah blah 1003 blah.
```

What I want to do is...

```
For Variable_1 As Integer = 1001 To 1010 AND 1111 To 1112
     RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & Variable_1 & " blah.")
Next
```

And get this...

```
Blah blah 1001 blah.
Blah blah 1002 blah.
Blah blah 1003 blah.
Blah blah 1111 blah.
Blah blah 1112 blah.
```

I know the syntax is not correct, so there is anyway to do that?

Comment: Please format your block of code using 4 leading spaces for each line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just split your loop into two?

```
For Variable_1 As Integer = 1001 To 1010 
     RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & Variable_1 & " blah.")
Next
For Variable_1 As Integer = 1111 To 1112
     RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & Variable_1 & " blah.")
Next
```

or set a condition:

```
For Variable_1 As Integer = 1001 To  1112
     If Not (Variable_1 > 1010 AndAlso Variable_1 < 1111) Then
    RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & Variable_1 & " blah.")
     End If
Next
```

Comment: I know, but this is just an example, the real one is much much bigger! This is why I am looking for a way to put it together.

Comment: Your second example is what I am looking for! It worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a really clean way to do this without too much repetition. Maybe:

```
For Each Variable_1 As Integer In Enumerable.Range(1001,10) _
                         .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1111,2))
     RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & Variable_1 & " blah.")
Next
```

Which relies on [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the `System.Linq` namespace (as is `Concat`)

Comment: that's a nice solution also...gotta mention you are missing a space in your code on `ForEach`, should be `For Each` (sorry for nitpicking, things like that drive me crazy!)

Comment: @RianBattle - fixed. *Mostly* writing C# most days at the moment, takes me a while to adjust back to VB.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, you could also store the values you want in a list and loop through those (of course, depending on the number of values you need, this might not be the best option).

```
Dim intList As New List(Of Integer) From {1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1111, 1112}
For Each item As Integer In intList
    RichTextBox_1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Blah blah " & item.ToString & " blah.")
Next
```